# names on the x-axis of barplot in R?

Tags: r, bar-chart

I am plotting a barplot in r, using the following data:

```
   ,Up,Down
Floor-1,690,1511
Maxim,1354,2515
Hosiptal,1358,2649
Bank,459,589
Air-port,1359,2097
Bus-stand,1234,1928
Taxi-Stand,213,138
Railway-station,557,610
```

My script is :

```
  d <- read.csv("file.csv")
  barplot(t(as.matrix(d[, 2:3])),beside=TRUE,legend = c("Up","Down"),  ylab = "Number of steps",
    xlab = "Building", main = "Up and Down steps",names.arg= as.matrix(d$X) ,col=rainbow(2),type="h")
```

In this plot the labels of x-axis "Bus-stand" and and "Railway-station" are missing.

How can I make these missing labels come back?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try making the labels smaller with cex.names

```
x<- c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)

names <- c("Name", "Long name", "This name is long", "Name", "Name")

barplot(x, names.arg=names)
# Names might not all fit, depending on size of graph
barplot(x, names.arg=names, cex.names=.5)
# All names will probably fit
```